# Apache POI 3.15 org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap missing

Tags: apache, apache-poi, apache-commons

I am using Apache POI 3.15 for reading Excel 2010 workbook. Even after adding the dependent jar - **commons-collections4-4.1.jar** in my build path (Eclipse), I get the class definition not found error for ListValuedMap class:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

What am I missing? Double checked the jar, even the ListValuedClass is there inside jar. Also tried adding it in "target platform" of Eclipse

Code

```
File excelFile = new File(excelFilePath);

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);
```

Comment: How did you add it to the build path? Did you also add it to the runtime path?

Comment: I am using the above code in a plugin project in Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2). So I tried adding to both target platform and build path (RMB on project - Build Path - Configure Build Path... - Add External Jars). Plugin projects in higher eclipse version does not provide the old way of adding runtime classpath

Comment: Please help on above problem.

Answer (score 2):

You Have To add Following Jar In You Project

- poi-3.17.jar
- poi-excelant-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- commons-collections-4-4.1.jar

After Then You can use Your Code

like..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Demo1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

            File f1 = new File("G:\\apachedemo.xlsx");
            FileOutputStream fileop = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            workbook.write(fileop);
            workbook.close();
            System.out.println("File Created...!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Main Error : "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use version Apache POI 3.17. I had the same issue when I used 3.16

Answer (score 0):

Please follow me.

[image]

You can download jar file from [Click website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1)

Hope is help.